# How to debug on exceptions inside try except block?

Tags: python, pycharm

The PyCharm debugger has the feature to set breakpoints at raised exceptions. However if an exception is handled inside a try except block it is not raised. How to deal with this if I want to debug within the try block? I could comment out the try except parts but this seems too cumbersome. Is there a better solution?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your question, but in theory, you could add breakpoints to the except AND to the try block, allowing you to stop in both places. You can also navigate using the debugging tool with F8 (it will move on to the next function).

Comment: @ThiagoSalvatore This is possible but I am to lazy to go manually to the line where the code breaks. Espceially if the error is deeply nested this is not an efficient solution.  I want that pycharm stops there automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the breakpoints settings (Either the [image: breakpoint symbol] icon in the debug toolbar, or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shft</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>), you can [set exception breakpoints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-breakpoints.html#exception-breakpoints).

The ***"[Activation Policy](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-breakpoints.html#properties)"*** is usually set by default to *"On termination"*. But since you handle the error, there is no termination. To activate the breakpoint immediately, even if the error is handled, you need to set the activation policy to *"On raise"*:

[image: showing the activation policy part in the settings, with On raise set]

***Note:*** that warning sign which says: *"This option may slow down the debugger"*